# Get value of Web Audio node or param after automation

Tags: web-audio-api

I would like to access a Web Audio Node's calculated output or param value at the current time (after any `connect`ed node's contributions have been added) in the main thread.

Currently all I can access is the value set using the AudioParam methods or the setter of AudioParam.value, but the contributions from any other nodes that I `connect` are not applied when using the AudioParam.value getter. Is this 1) intentional and 2) are there any workarounds to get the actual value in the main thread that a AudioWorkletProcessor would receive (which would sum the values from each input and add that to the `value`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ConstantSourceNode` with appropriate automations of the `offset` `AudioParam`.  Then connect some signal to the `offset` and finally look at the output of the node to see the computed value.  You still need to use an `AnalyserNode`, `ScriptProcessorNode`, or `AudioWorkletNode` to get at the output values.

This isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: Yes the issue with using an AudioWorkletNode is that the place that has access to the output (after all automation and inputs have been accounted for) is in a separate thread. I created an issue in the spec repo, but it seems it is intentionally designed out of the system. AudioWorkletNode, SharedArrayBuffer and poor timing it is :/